# How many strings are in jvm string pool intern

Tags: java, string, profiling

I am profiling an application and the use of intern to input strings really helps. 
What I want to find is a good number to use for the object pool so I will not have performance penalty.
How can I know how many strings were inserted into the intern pool?

I am running some production trace, I cannot really count the input.

Does the JVM offer an api for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting with JDK7, you can use the `-XX:+PrintStringTableStatistics` JVM flag to print information about the size of the string table, such as the number of buckets and the size of a bucket.

You can also use the `jmap` tool by calling the command `jmap -heap *process_id*` which would show at the end the number of strings interned and the total size (also requires JDK7+).

Check [this blog post](http://xmlandmore.blogspot.com/2013/05/understanding-string-table-size-in.html) for more details.

Comment: This prints the statistics once to standard output, I would like to monitor this somehow. since it releases strings not used, I want to see the maximum number of strings occupying it in the application life cycle.

Comment: Another useful blog post on this topic: [*String.intern in Java 6, 7 and 8 – string pooling*](http://java-performance.info/string-intern-in-java-6-7-8/) by [Mikhail Vorontsov](http://java-performance.info/author/Mike/)